# How can I make the horizontal scrolling smooth when using a Mac trackpad?

Tags: jquery, macos, scroll, trackpad

I've made a website with horizontal scroll, but there is a problem with the acceleration of the Mac trackpad that makes it not very smooth.

The website can be viewed here: [www.runeneesgaard.dk](http://www.runeneesgaard.dk)

This is the code that I use to make the page go to the right when the user scroll down on his or her mousewheel:

```
 $(function() {
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Does anybody have an idea as to how I can make this smooth and work with the acceleration of the Mac trackpad? Or maybe "ignore" the acceleration?

I hope it makes sense! :)

Thanks!